# Recursion range question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A sequence $\{a_n\}$ is defined recursively by
$a_1 = 1, a_2 = 3 \text{ and } a_n = 2a_{n - 1} - a_{n - 2} \text{ for } n \geq 3$. Then $a_n = 2n - 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Is the range $n \geq 3$ in place so $n$ is always a natural number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no reason to restrict your inductive hypothesis to $3 \le k$.  I would make the inductive hypothesis $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$, if $1 \le k < n$ then $f(k) = 5^k + (-1)^k$.

Now, to prove that $f(n) = 5^n + (-1)^n$:  You've already checked it for $n = 1,2$, so you can assume $n \ge 3$.  We will need to apply the given fact that:
$$
(*) \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, f(n+2) = 4f(n+1) + 5f(n).
$$
I think the crucial point you are missing is that since this statement starts with "$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$," you can apply it to any natural number.  Since $n \ge 3$, $n-2 \in \mathbb{N}$, so you can apply ($*$) to $n-2$.  In other words, you can plug in $n-2$ for $n$ in ($*$).  This gives you:
$$
f(n) = 4f(n-1) + 5f(n-2).
$$
Now since $1 \le n-1, n-2 < n$, you can apply your inductive hypothesis to $n-1$ and $n-2$.

Comment: Right.  And notice that it wouldn't work if you restrict your inductive hypothesis to $3 \le k < n$, because we don't know $3 \le n-2$.  But since $n \ge 3$, we have $1 \le n-2, n-1 < n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\require{cancel}f(n-2)=5^{n-2}+(-1)^{n-2}$ and $f(n-1)=5^{n-1}+(-1)^{n-1}$, then\begin{align}f(n)&=4f(n-1)+5f(n-2)\\&=4\bigl(5^{n-1}+(-1)^{n-1}\bigr)+5\bigl(5^{n-2}+(-1)^{n-2}\bigr)\\&=(5-1)\times5^{n-1}+4(-1)(-1)^{n-2}+5\times5^{n-2}+5(-1)^{n-2}\\&=5\times 5^{n-1}-\cancel{5^{n-1}}+\cancel{5\times5^{n-2}}+(-4+5)(-1)^{n-2}\\&=5^n+(-1)^n.\end{align}

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: That is almost correct. But did not just pick up $n-2$. I picked up $n-2$ *and* $n-1$ (both of which belong to that range).